# classProbs for Random Forest Regression in R with caret

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am performing a Random Forest Regression in R, but would like to get something similar to class Probabilities as Random Forest Classification. In the past, I have ran Random Forest Classification models and have been able to get how accurate the prediction is.  Is there a similar concept within Random Forest Regression?

For the following code:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(## 5-fold CV
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  search = 'grid',
  classProbs = TRUE,
  savePredictions = "final"
)
grid <- expand.grid(.mtry=seq(1,4,1))
set.seed(123)
rf_model <- train(iris$Sepal.length~.,
                  data = iris[-5],
                  method = "rf",
                  importance=TRUE,
                  trControl = fitControl
                  metric = "MAE",
                  tuneGrid=grid,
                  ntree=100
)
```

]

Comment: `caret` package only tunes `mtry` as you are using `randomForest` package. If you want to tune nodsize you have to use `ranger` package. Preprocess does not do centering and scaling automatically. It is better to apply centering and scaling with pa.

Comment: Okay. But for nodesize, can we just assign something random then and go with it?